# What is the name of the weapon shown in the image below?

Tags: middle-ages, weapons

[image]

I am looking for the proper name of the sword in the image below. I was not sure which stack exchange site to post this on so I put it here, figuring it was a type of medieval weaponry, if an obscure one.

Comment: It looks to be a fantasia double headed version of the early modern war pick or horsemans pick or war hammer with pick head.

Comment: What about the long bladed part leading up to the pick though? It looks like some type of sword, to me at least.

Comment: A FANTASY thing vaguely resembling a weird kind of axe. It's the first time I see a book being used as add-on armor on a pauldron.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for the identification of an artists fantasy.

Answer (score 7):

It's probably something someone just made up. There is something similar, but I couldn't find a name for it. It was made in Liberia. Here's a hyperlink to the image from the [Spencer Museum of Art](http://collection.spencerart.ku.edu/eMuseumPlus?service=ExternalInterface&module=collection&objectId=33276&viewType=detailView).

Update: Commenter justCal referred to it as a *kuba sword*. Google search confirms.

[image: Spencer Museum of Art]

Comment: You will find this style weapon often listed as a *kuba sword*.

Comment: See also [this semi-related question on SciFi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120844/were-the-isengard-uruk-hai-swords-supposed-to-be-armor-piercing) about L-shape swords in a particularly popular fantasy work.